# how do you set session attributes with java.net.URLConnection?

Tags: java, session, urlconnection, setattribute

**how do you set session attributes with `java.net.URLConnection` or its subclasses?**

In other words, what is the equivalent of `HttpSession.setAttribute(String, Object)` in `Java.net.URLConnection`? `URLConnection` does have `setRequestProperty(String, String)`, but it does not help me as I need similar functionality as `session.setAttribute(String, Object)` for setting a timestamp.

**In other words, how do you express following call with URLConnection?**
`HttpSession.setAttribute("timestamp", timestamp);`

I cant change the contract with the third party, that is my request must have an timestamp attribute with a `java.util.Date` value.

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can't. The session is kept, privately, at server-side, and is not available from the client. It's not part of the HTTP protocol at all, but is just something that nearly all server-side webapp APIs offer to allow keeping state associated to one particular user of the application.

Basically, what you're asking is the equivalent of "what can I put in my email to store some text in the `C:\session.txt` file on the hard drive of the recipient?":

- there is perhaps no `C:\session.txt` file
- you can't access the hard drive of a recipient by writing something in an email. It would constitute a big security problem